# Junk Mail folder in Hotmail won't sync with Outlook 2011 for Mac Junk mail folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention, microsoft-outlook-2011

I just installed Office 2011 on my MacBook and then connected it to my hotmail plus account.  It all works fine except the junk mail in the hotmail junk folder does not flow over to Outlook 2011.  How can I sync up those two folders?

Answer (score 0):

Neither do sent, deleted mail folders. As far as I researched there is no way to achieve what we need elegantly due to POP protocol's shortage.